# How to send email using Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

Here is my Route.php

```
Route::get('invitations' , 'Invitationscontroller@accept');
```

Below is my Invitationscontroller.php

```
public function accept(){

        $email_id =  Users::select('email_id')->get();

        Mail::send('test' , array('user' => $email_id) , function ($message){

            $message -> to('xyzabc@gmail.com' ) -> subject ('Welcome!!!');
        });
        return "Success";
    }
```

I have configured `mail.php` as per requirements stated in tutorial.

When I run the URL, I get the error as

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
"
```

Where m I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message clearly says, you have a problem with the authentication towards your mail providers SMTP.

You need to configure your mail settings in your `.env` file, see sample data:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Please check that you entered valid data.

Comment: `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp  
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com  
MAIL_PORT=587  
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername  MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: I have configured .env file with this input, still getting the same error.

Comment: Try if `MAIL_USERNAME=MyUsername@gmail.com` works and refresh your Laravel cache afterwards with `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Now it is showing this error.                                                                                                                   `Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 i20sm5418126pfj.91 - gsmtp`
"